# Linux KDE Login Script

Tags: linux

I've been trying to set up a server that I want to run when I log in (in case the computer crashes or anything like that).

The script works and it runs on log in but it runs in the background or something as when I use `ps -A` I can see the process running. This is ok but the server is interactive so I want it to start in a terminal window and keep that window open after the user is logged in so that commands can be issued to the server. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about starting your script like:

```
xterm -e YOURSCRIPT
```

Or if you prefer to use KDE's `konsole`:

```
konsole -e YOURSCRIPT
```

Those open a terminal window to run the specified command after `-e`.

HTH